# How can I get and manage a stream resource of DB? PHP-DB2

Tags: php, yii, db2, clob, php-stream-wrappers

I am manage CLOB and BLOB types with DB2, PHP and Yii Framework (although I am using only php). I am getting to upload files to DB2. With CLOB and BLOB types. But I have a problem, I don't get to download files. I obtain a resource, stream type with this code:

```
if(is_resource($model->file_content)) echo 'resource of type:';
echo '<br>';
echo get_resource_type($model->file_content);
```

I need to convert this stream in a file to download in a web.

I've tried: `print_r( stream_get_contents($model->file_content));`

and using `fread()`

Are there any php function to get the stream type?

**Edit:** The type is "ibm PDO Lob stream", It get with `stream_get_meta_data($model->file_content);`

Also, I've tried:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  
header('Content-length: '.$model->file_size);
header('Content-Type: '.$model->file_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$model->file_name);

echo $model->file_content;
```

But the result is a file with html of my page.

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write pure `PHP` code. `Yii` has a method called `sendFile` which handles this. Take a look:

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile('file.ext', "Content Of File", "Mime Time",TRUE);
```

As official document defines `sendFile()`:

> Sends a file to user.

```
public void sendFile(string $fileName, string $content, string $mimeType=NULL, boolean $terminate=true)
```

It is also suggested to use Yii's **[CFileHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper)** class too.

Comment: I don't want to send a file. I need to insert and get files in a CLOB column of DB2.

Comment: @vicenrele Actually `sendFile` use case is to download a file. Or may be this is my misunderstanding? Are you talking about downloading the Clob file or storing|interaction clob with DB2?